# Show left to right

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

So I have problems with sliding from left to right div with display:none.

```
<div class="second">
<li><a id="sale_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['sale_man'];?></a></li>
<li><a id="purch_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['purch_man'];?></a></li>
<li><a id="load_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['load_man'];?></a></li>
<li><a id="acc_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['acc_man'];?></a></li>
</ul></div>
<div  class="third" style="display: none;" >
lolo</div>

$('#sale_man').click(function(){
     $('.third').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

So after clicking on id="sale_man" i need to slide div with class 3, but nothing happens..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong. First the missing `<ul>` tag that Yorgo identified.

The second is this line

```
$('.third').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

If you change it to

```
$('.third').show();
```

You will see that the div will appear (but without the animation you want). Which means that you have the wrong syntax.

If you look at the [API documentation page for `show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

You will see there is no version of the function that takes in arguments like you have in your code.

So either you should have a custom `show` function in your code somewhere, that overrides jQuery's one. Or you should be including a jQuery plugin that supports the functionality that you are after.

**EDIT:** it would seem that you are missing [this jQuery UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/)

Comment: yes, all is right, but the latest ui is already included and the ul also is, but i just forget to copy. And also through firebug i can see that something is changing on click, but dispay:none is still in code...

Comment: Look at this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mLg8H/1/ . It works for me so something else must be wrong. Perhaps whatever is being echoed from your php code.

Comment: thans, as i see, there nothing changed in my code... echos only word from lang array.

Answer (score -1):

you forget  tag

```
<div class="second">
    <ul>
    <li><a id="sale_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['sale_man'];?></a></li>
    <li><a id="purch_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['purch_man'];?></a></li>
    <li><a id="load_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['load_man'];?></a></li>
    <li><a id="acc_man" rel="showinfo"><?php echo $lang['acc_man'];?></a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

Comment: And what? I asked about showing the div with class third, not about html code. I just forget to copy that ul.